# django, problem with the - contact - keyword

Tags: django, view

I am new to django and trying to create a `contact` page.

Here is my `urls.py` in the app folder:

```
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("contacts", contact_view),
]
```

and my `views.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

contact_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Contact Page</h1>')
```

Everything works fine when trying: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts`

I've noticed when I change `contacts` to `contact` as the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("contact", contact_view),
]
```

and then try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact`,

it gives:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/
Using the URLconf defined in config.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. admin/
2. 
3. about
4. contact 
The current path, contact/, didn’t match any of these.
```

I've tried restarting the server and the VSCode. Not working!

Appreciate any help on this.

`Windows 11`, `VSCode`, `django 4.2.4`

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your urlpatterns.

urls.py (the one from your app, *not your project's urls.py*)

```py
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path("contact", views.contact_view),
]
```

views.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def contact_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Contact Page</h1>')
```

**Working example**:

[image: working_contact_page]

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the `contact` keyword, it is just a trailing slash, the pattern, for both `contact` and `contacts` should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/', contact_view),
]
```

the browser here has made a request *with* a slash, if that is not the case, Django will first look for a pattern without the slash, and then *with* a trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My main curiosity is why there is a difference between `contacts` and `contact` here (without using a trailing slash). I've tested `about` also and it worked. It seems the problem is with `contact` only.

Comment: Another question: When do we use a trailing slash? I assume for the URL patterns that represent a single resource like the `contact` page, we do not use a trailing slash.

Comment: @AfshinDavoudy: it is not with `contact`, it was likely just that your browser put a slash after it, and for the rest, it did not (for example because you removed it, or entered it that fast that the browser did not append it).

Comment: Normally a slash is always added, this is what the `APPEND_SLASH` setting is about: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#append-slash